# SVN Subversion : post-branch-switch hook

Tags: svn, hook

I want to run a script **after switching branch** in SVN using hooks, but:

- the only hooks I found in Tortoise interface are the combinatory of the following : Start/Pre/Post Commit/Update
- In the doc they mention the following templates :

```
> ls depot/hooks/
post-commit.tmpl post-unlock.tmpl pre-revprop-change.tmpl
post-lock.tmpl pre-commit.tmpl pre-unlock.tmpl
post-revprop-change.tmpl pre-lock.tmpl start-commit.tmpl
```

but none of those seems to apply to branch-switchs ..?

**How can I setup running scripts automaticaly after branch-switch in SVN ?**

Comment: What do you want to do with such a hook script? Switching to a branch is an entirely client-side operation, so nothing on the server side will help you. And there is no such hook on TortoiseSVN's side too.

Comment: I hadn't realized that hooks were only on the server-side, which indeed is problematic of my use case. The script I want to run basicaly moves files around using copy/paste (with a python script, so I expect the hooked script will just contain something like 'python my_script.py')

Comment: Use a script that can run `svn switch` and also runs your stuff and use it instead of calling `svn switch` directly.

Comment: I guess there is a case to be made about creating **client-side hooks** _but_ that is way outside the scope of the question, I would suppose.